# Rails gem fork issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm applying a patch to my fork of 2.3.15 rails for a workaround for one of the latest security issues.

Previously in my gem file I had -

```
gem 'rails', '2.3.15'
```

And everything worked as expected. But for my fork I have

```
gem 'rails', '2.3.15', :git => 'git@github.com:myrepo/rails.git', :branch => 'CVE-2013-0155-fix'
```

After doing a bundle install and then running my app with bundle exec ruby script/server as per usual, I'm getting this error -

```
| ./script/../config/boot.rb:64:in `require': no such file to load -- initializer (LoadError)
```

I thought that maybe I had just messed something up with my fork but when I point my gemfile to the rails git repo I get the same issue.

```
gem 'rails', '2.3.15', :git => 'git@github.com:rails/rails.git', :tag => 'v2.3.15'
```

Can anyone explain to me what's up?

Comment: you are using the version AND branch or tag. could you remove the version and just reference a specific revision?

Comment: If I remove the version and point to the v2.3.15 tag on rails/rails I get 
`Could not find gem 'rails (>= 0) ruby' in git@github.com:rails/rails.git (at v2.3.15).
Source does not contain any versions of 'rails (>= 0) ruby'`

Pointing at my forked branch I get
`Git error: command git rev-parse CVE-2013-0155-fix in directory xxx/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.01/cache/bundler/git/rails-xxx has failed.
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory 'xxx/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.01/cache/bundler/git/rails-xxx'`

Answer (score 0):

Found an excellent blogpost on the issue here - http://robanderson123.wordpress.com/2013/01/05/applying-backported-security-patches-to-rails-2-3/

The big problem being that rails/2-3-stable doesn't have any gemspecs in the repo. Long story short, did a `bundle install` with rails set to 2.3.15. Copied the rails gemspecs for activerecord etc out of the specifications directory `bundle show rails` gives into each of the corresponding directories in my fork of rails. With the exception of the rails gemspec which I copied into the railties directory.

After this `gem 'rails', '2.3.15', :git => 'git@github.com:myrepo/rails.git', :branch => 'my-2-3-branch'` works as expected.